# How to dynamically display a contact form 7 based on the page link?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have list of staff names on page using TablePress....would like to have each name hyperlinked or linked to a contact form vs. the staff member's actual email address.

I do I insert short code for contact form into link to staff members name showing in table on my webpage.

Comment: Please also take a look at https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to link to a [page that uses a page template](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/), and add a URI attribute that defines which form to load.  So for example,

```
<a href="/staff-form-page/?form=1">staff 1</a>
<a href="/staff-form-page/?form=2">staff 2</a>
```

on the form page template (with slug `staff-form-page`), progammatically insert your cf7 form with the [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function.

```
<?php
if( isset( $_GET['form'] ) ){
  do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="'+$_GET['form']+'"]' );
}
?>
```